# undefined (type []DataReponse has no field or method)

Tags: go

I'm trying to compile the following piece of code

```
    var result []DataReponse
    if result.Commenter == "teacher"{
        sender = models.CommentUser{
            Name:result.UserName,
            Email:result.UserEmail,
        }
    }else{
        sender = models.CommentUser{
            Name:result.ChildName,
            Email:result.ChildEmail,
    }
```

I am receiving the error `result.Commenter undefined (type []DataReponse has no field or method Commenter)` here is my struct

```
//DataReponse is the structure of the response
type DataReponse struct{
  CommentText   string              `json:"comment_text"`
  Commenter     string              `json:"commenter"`
  ChildEmail    core.NullString     `json:"child_email"`
  ChildName     core.NullString       `json:"child_name"`
  UserName      core.NullString       `json:"user_name"`
  UserEmail     core.NullString       `json:"user_email"`
}
```

how can i use result values ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[]DataReponse` is a slice of `DataReponse`s, i.e., there may be more than one response (or none). You could use a [for loop](https://golang.org/ref/spec#For_statements) to run some code for each `struct DataReponse` returned. I would consider doing [the tour](https://tour.golang.org/welcome/2).

Comment: Avising doing a complete language tour for just one question is not very constructive

Answer (score 3):

As explained by twotwotwo you are working with a slice. Loop over it like so.

```
    for _, data := range result {
       if data.Commenter == "teacher" {
         ...   
        }
    }
```